# Mongo charts managing via CI/CD

Tags: mongodb

Is there a way to manage mongo charts via git repo and CI/CD tools? I mean storing charts config somewhere and get them created automaticaly after running CD pipelines. I am looking for some analog of changelog for liquibase. I just do not want to create my charts by hands on each environment. I prefer to make their creation/update via deployment process.